# How to get list of variables referenced in a liquid template

Tags: ruby, liquid

I'm working on a project which uses the Liquid template language.  I have a page with iframes showing some rendered liquid templates and an editor section.  In the editor section the user can change the values of some of the variables referred to in the liquid templates.  At this point some of the templates need to be re-rendered but I only want to re-render those templates which refer to the variable which has been changed.

The point I'm stuck on is how best to get a list of the variables referred to in a liquid template.

So if I do this:

```
templates=[]
templates[0] = Liquid::Template.parse("hi {{name}}") 
templates[1] = Liquid::Template.parse("my cat is called {{cat_name}}")
```

I want to know that 'name' is referenced but that (e.g.) 'cat' is not in template 0.  Then when name is changed I can re-render template[0] and when cat is changed I can re-render template[1].

I've found that I can get a list of nodes and check each one to see if it is a variable, e.g. templates[0].root.nodelist[1] has a type of 'Liquid::Variable' but the 'name' method of the variable returns an object of type 'Liquid::VariableLookup' which in turn doesn't seem to have a method for getting a name out of it and this feels like I might be going about it the wrong way.

Comment: OK so maybe it's a bug, I just filed this: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/547

Comment: The behaviour for this was changed as a result of me asking the liquid developers about this, this behaviour is supported from liquid 4.0.2

Answer (score 11):

Following https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/685#issuecomment-471499796 you can use `FileTreeVisitor` class for that. Namely:

```
template = Liquid::Template.parse("hi {{name}}")

Liquid::ParseTreeVisitor.for(template.root)
  .add_callback_for(Liquid::VariableLookup) do |node|
  [node.name, *node.lookups].join('.')
end.visit.flatten.compact # => ["name"]
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

`Liquid::VariableLookup` has a `name` method. This works:

```
markup = 'My name is {{ my_name }} and I live in {{ my_address}}.'
template = Liquid::Template.parse(markup)  
template.root.nodelist
  .select{ |node| node.is_a?(Liquid::Variable)}
  .map{ |var| var.name.name } # => ["my_name", "my_address"]
```

but it may be problematic if the markup has other tags. The solution will fail with this markup:

```
'My name is {% if condition == "big" %} Big {% endif %} {{ name }}'
```

It fails to catch the variable `condition` inside the `if` tag. It's better to stick with the `ParseTreeVisitor` solution suggested by @asok.